# MySQL InnoDB's History Length is growing while mysqldump is in progress

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump, percona

I'm using a 3-node group replication cluster of Percona MySQL (8.0.25) behind ProxySQL nodes (2.3.2). The `transaction-isolation` param is set to `READ-COMMITTED`.

While I'm running `mysqldump` (through ProxySQL if it matters somehow)

`mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf --add-drop-trigger --all-databases --events --lock-for-backup --max-allowed-packet=1G --no-autocommit --routines --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables -ubackup -h127.0.0.1 -pxxxxxxxxxxx --port=6033`

InnoDB's History Length (`trx_rseg_history_len`) is growing fast. Usually, I have values near 1k, but while `mysqldump`, I observe 6kk+.

[image]

Following the recipe from [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/05/08/chasing-a-hung-transaction-in-mysql-innodb-history-length-strikes-back/), I see the next transactions

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718894
         TIMER_WAIT: 37621000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_create_db
              QUERY: SHOW CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `auth`
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718895
         TIMER_WAIT: 27901000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/savepoint
              QUERY: SAVEPOINT sp
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: 00000
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 3. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718896
         TIMER_WAIT: 554664000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_tables
              QUERY: show tables
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 4. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718897
         TIMER_WAIT: 581915000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_table_status
              QUERY: show table status like 'account'
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 5. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718898
         TIMER_WAIT: 34781000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/set_option
              QUERY: SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: 00000
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 6. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718899
         TIMER_WAIT: 33191000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/set_option
              QUERY: SET SESSION character_set_results = 'binary'
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: 00000
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 7. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718900
         TIMER_WAIT: 158103000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_create_table
              QUERY: show create table `account`
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 8. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718901
         TIMER_WAIT: 38441000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/set_option
              QUERY: SET SESSION character_set_results = 'utf8mb4'
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: 00000
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 9. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718902
         TIMER_WAIT: 596614000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_fields
              QUERY: show fields from `account`
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
*************************** 10. row ***************************
     processlist_id: 629626
               user: backup
        trx_started: 2022-10-17 12:33:02
trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
           EVENT_ID: 1718903
         TIMER_WAIT: 544844000
         EVENT_NAME: statement/sql/show_fields
              QUERY: show fields from `account`
  RETURNED_SQLSTATE: NULL
        MYSQL_ERRNO: 0
       MESSAGE_TEXT: NULL
             ERRORS: 0
           WARNINGS: 0
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know that, in general, the `READ-COMMITTED` transaction isolation level shouldn't be followed by history length growing. Here I see `REPEATABLE-READ`, which is reasonable because of the `--single-transaction` parameter of `mysqldump`. I have a relatively high load, near 40k QPS to a cluster, so the history length is growing fast while the backup runs ~1h.

Is there a way to deal with history length growing to prevent performance degradation?

Comment: Consider taking the node out of the cluster during the backup.  Or check out gh-ost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a natural consequence of a long-running transaction on a database instance that has high traffic. That is, you are running lots of transactions, but the garbage-collection of the backlog of transactions and old row versions is hindered by the long-running transaction.

Since the HLL corrects itself rapidly after your mysqldump is over, I wouldn't worry about it.

If you are seeing measurable performance degradation of other queries during the mysqldump, I'd suggest creating a replica and run the mysqldump against the replica. This is a pretty popular solution.

By the way, the mysqldump transaction must be REPEATABLE-READ, to ensure a consistent backup.